# Mangled fonts in GUI applications on Debian 11

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, fonts, gui, debian-bullseye

I have a pretty fresh Debian 11 installation, running in a VirtualBox VM on Windows 10. The fonts in question look as if each glyph has many missing parts / as if the visible parts, such as they are, are correct.

I must have forgotten to install or configure something, I think.

A workaround is, in `VirtualBox Manager | Settings | Display | Screen | Extended Features`, to uncheck the checkbox 'Enable 3D Acceleration'.
That, however has performance implications. And my Debian 10 guest works fine with this option being enabled.

Visual Studio Code has a mangled title bar, but all text inside the application renders correctly:
[image: Title Bar of VSCode with mangled font]

MonoDevelop is completely fubar:
[image: Startup screen of MonoDevelop with mangled font]

Jetbrains Rider the same:
[image: Startup screen of Jetbrains Rider with mangled font]

Attempts to diagnose the problem:

- I tried all the pre-installed GUI applications and none of those are affected,
- all three applications display fine on a Debian 10 similarly set up and running in the same VBox,
- only Rider produces any errors and it produces the same ones (line-identical) on Debian 10, where "it just works"(TM), so those errors are unrelated.

I am a bit lost.

... Probably unrelated: I have the same issue on Android 11 in BlueStacks 10 with Firefox. I am adding this in case the issue is not of the client OS but of the server OS or virtualisation software.

Comment: Note: I have tagged `virtualbox` and `virtual-machine` not knowing, whether those are related. I think they must be, because if Debian-on-metal were affected, I'd expect easily found bug reports for all three applications - and I found none. Should a solution be found, that is unrelated to running in a VM, I will cull these tags.

Comment: Did you install Guest Extensions? You need to do that.

Comment: @John: Yes, of course. They work for screen resizing and multi-monitor usage (or rather neither of these two worked before I had the guest extensions installed).

Comment: I have use the following but I recommend you back up the machine before trying:    ...   sudo apt-get --fix-missing update ...  to get missing updates. Then  ....   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  ....    to install new dependencies

Comment: @John : No effect, not better nor worse. What it did was install `linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64` and remove `linux-image-5.10.0-26-amd64`. Interestingly, `linux-image-5.10.0-27-amd64` was previously and is still also installed.